# jquery validate stops mvc5 unobtrusive validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple view that has a form backed by this view model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool ShowDescription { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

When I click 'save' if the Name field is empty then I see the boiler plate validation message as I would expect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#MyForm").validate({
    rules: {
        "Description":{
            required: "#ShowDescriptionCheckbox:checked"
        }
    },

    messages: {
        "Description": {
            required: "Enter a Description"
        }
    },

    errorElement: "span",

    errorClass: "field-validation-error",

});
</script>
```

Now I have some (above) javascript to implement a validation rule which checks Description is not empty if ShowDescription has been checked. NOTE -

If you click the button with just the checkbox selected then I see the jQuery message saying Description is required. However, there is no validation error on the Name field. It is like the validation stopped once it found the first failure. If the user now completes the description and hits Save again, the jQuery validation message is cleared correctly, and the validation error on the Name field is now shown.

This does at least prevent the form from being submitted incorrectly, however it is a poor user experience.

Is there a way I can get all of the validation errors shown at the same time so that the user knows exactly what needs to be corrected.

My _layout.cshtml file includes the following:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

When I look at F12 in Chrome there are no missing scripts, and as I have said before, the individual validators work on their own, its just when they are both required to display at the same time it breaks down.

Comment: The correct way to handle this is to use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue("ShowDescription")]` or similar validation attribute applied to your `Description` property

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the suggestion, it looks like this will achieve what I'm looking for. However, I am interested to know what the correct way is to get these two validation methods playing nicely. Or am I experiencing the expected behaviour and i need to use a plug-in like the one suggested?

Comment: The problem you have is than internally `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` initiaizes `jquery.validate.js` (setting the rules etc based on the `data-val` attributes in your form controls) making it difficult to add/override those that have been added. You can do this using the `$.validator.addMethod()` and `$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add()` functions (which is what foolproof does, or what you would do if you wrote you own validation attribute). And the main advantage of using a validation attribute is that you get both client and server side validation out of the box.